# How to configure JoinEnrichment in NIFI to Join two Flowfiles?

Tags: apache-nifi

How to configure JOINEnrichment to JOIN two flowfiles , I have selected the JOIN strategy to be SQL but for the query should I use flow file method or original and enriched method ?